# Vim-go package. Almost none of the :GoXxxxx commands are available

Tags: plugin-vim-go

I have added the vim-go package to vim 8.2.716.

I used the "vim-packages" method, of cloning a git repostitory

```
git clone https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.git ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go
```

And then I have run `:GoInstallBinaries` from vim, apparently successfully.

I am following the install instructions at `https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt`

I now have syntax formatting, and it will highlight syntax errors found when I compile.  On loading a go program I get an information line `vim-go initialised gopls`. `set ft?` returns `filetype=go` and  `:filetype` prints `filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON`

But I have none of the `:GoXxxxx` commands, except `:GoInstallBinaries` and `:GoPath`.  In particular, I can't use `:GoBuild` to compile.

Have I missed an installation step.  Is there something I need to add to .vimrc or otherwise?

output of :scriptnames

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim82/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: ~/.vim/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
  9: ~/.vim/plugin/filebrowser.vim
 10: ~/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim
 11: ~/.vim/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
 12: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/plugin/go.vim
 13: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/config.vim
 14: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/util.vim
 15: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/ftdetect/gofiletype.vim
 16: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/syntax/go.vim
 17: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/lsp.vim
 18: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/path.vim
 19: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/job.vim
 20: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/lsp/message.vim
 21: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/uri.vim
 22: ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/autoload/go/statusline.vim
```

My vimrc, which now works (for me):

```
version 6.0
if &cp | set nocp | endif
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim
map! <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
vmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
nmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
map <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
vnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis :call netrw#BrowseXVis()
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseX :call netrw#BrowseX(expand((exists("g:netrw_gx")? g:netrw_gx : '<cfile>')),netrw#CheckIfRemote())
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
set background=dark
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set expandtab
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
set guifont=Fantasque\ Sans\ Mono\ 11
set helplang=en
set nomodeline
set mouse=a
set printoptions=paper:a4
set ruler
filetype plugin indent on
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim81,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
set shiftwidth=4
set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
set tabstop=4
set termencoding=utf-8
"colorscheme darkblue
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
let g:tex_flavor="latex"
"part is not a folding section in examclass"
let g:Tex_FoldedSections='chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
" vim: set ft=vim :
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you trying the other commands with a `*.go` file being edited? They usually depend on the file type... You can also check that `:set ft?` and confirm Vim detects it as `filetype=go`.

Comment: Yes, I am editing a file with a .go filetype. :set ft? returns filetype=go  and there is correct syntax hilighting etc.

Comment: What does the command `:filetype` say? You want it to include `plugin:ON`.

Comment: filetype detection:ON  plugin: ON indent: ON

Comment: Try `:scriptnames` (after opening a Go file) and see if a file with name ending in `ftplugin/go/commands.vim` is on the list? That's the file in vim-go that will set up commands such as `:GoBuild`...

Comment: Okay, that's not there, I've put the full output of scriptnames in the question.

Comment: Can you double check that this path exists under `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/`? Because if filetype plug-in is ON and filetype is being detected as `go`, it *should* load the `ftplugin/go/*.vim` files (also `ftplugin/go.vim` and `ftplugin/go_*.vim`) from packages that are enabled...

Comment: Yes  the path `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/ftplugin/go/` exists and the file commands.vim is there.

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you are... Do you actually have `filetype plugin indent on` somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`? I wonder if somehow it's not set that way when the `*.go` file is loaded and only somehow set later than that... But I'm really grasping at straws here...

Comment: YES!  the filetype line in my vimrc was put after the set truntime path line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why you're having the problem and why moving the `filetype` command above the setting of `runtimepath` is fixing it.

The problem is that your setting of `'runtimepath'` is incorrect, in that it's listing directory `/usr/share/vim/vim81`, which doesn't really match your version of Vim, and I expect this directory does not exist. From your mention that you're using Vim 8.2.716 and the output of `:scriptnames`, it really looks like `/usr/share/vim/vim82` is the correct directory with the Vim runtimes.

But as you can see in [`:help :filetype-plugin-on`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype-plugin-on):

> If filetype detection was not switched on yet, it will be as well. **This actually loads the file `ftplugin.vim` in `'runtimepath'`.**

So if your `'runtimepath'` is incorrect and doesn't include the directory where `ftplugin.vim` is located (which should be `/usr/share/vim/vim82` on your system), then `filetype plugin on` will fail.

There are a few ways to fix it. One is to fix the typo in the directory name. You can also use the `$VIMRUNTIME` to always refer to the directory with the Vim runtimes on your system. As per [`:help 'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27):

> You probably should always include `$VIMRUNTIME` somewhere, to use the distributed runtime files. You can put a directory before `$VIMRUNTIME` to find files which replace a distributed runtime files. You can put a directory after `$VIMRUNTIME` to find files which add to distributed runtime files.

A better option is to avoid overwriting `'runtimepath'` as a whole. It seems the point of it is to add `/var/lib/vim/addons` (and `/var/lib/vim/addons/after`) to your `'runtimepath'`. If that's still important for you (I don't see any plugins being loaded from there), then you could accomplish something similar (though not exactly the same) with:

```
set runtimepath^=/var/lib/vim/addons
set runtimepath+=/var/lib/vim/addons/after
```

This will add them to the very beginning and very end to the list. It's not *exactly* where they are in your current setting (which is actually after/before the user `~/.vim` directory), but maybe that's a close enough approximation? You can do some more gymnastics to get it exactly where you want it (perhaps a Vimscript function to split `&runtimepath` into a list, insert the two items you want into the exact position after the local ones but before the system ones, then join that back together into a list), but that's probably overkill.

---

A few more things from your vimrc:

1. `version 6.0`: Not really needed anymore. It's actually ignored in recent versions of Vim. In any case, it's hard to even *find* a Vim version older than 7.4 these days...
2. `if &cp | set nocp | endif`: You can just `set nocp` (or [`set nocompatible`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27)) directly, though modern versions of Vim already default to `nocompatible` when a user vimrc file is found. So while it's fine to keep, strictly speaking, it's not even necessary.
3. `let s:cpo_save=&cpo`, `set cpo&vim` and then `let &cpo=s:cpo_save` and `unlet s:cpo_save`: This is simply temporarily setting `nocompatible` inside the block where these mappings are created ([`set cpo&vim`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27) sets exactly those compatibility options.) . But since you're already in `nocompatible` mode (both because you're setting it explicitly *and* because it's the default in modern Vim when a user vimrc file is found), there's no need to go through all this trouble.

Comment: Thanks again,  I suspect much of that vimrc has grown over time. I certainly have no memory of actually adding anyting except the latex bit at the end.  I've done some significant pruning with no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

The line in the `.vimrc`

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

needs to be put before the line that sets the runtime path, otherwise when the *.go file is loaded the plugin is not set.

Moving the line earlier in the `.vimrc` allows the plugin to be fully loaded. (As suggested by – filbranden)

Comment: Huh... While I'm glad you solved your issue, the position of the line in your vimrc shouldn't really affect how or whether plug-ins are loaded... So I'm not sure that's exactly the reason why it didn't work. On the other hand, you mentioned setting runtime path and that's a bit unusual. Why are you setting it explicitly? Can you share more of your vimrc file?

Comment: Added to the question.